# CAML Query to Filter On DateTime Field using DateDiff

Tags: caml, query

I'm looking to use javascript and CAML to place a value on a SharePoint page.
I need to find the current On-Call person based on the start and end date of a list item, and the next on-call person based on the same criteria. 
I've done this in PowerApps with a lookup() and datadiff(), but I'm having trouble converting this to CAML.

PowerApps query:

```
LookUp('PowerAppConnection', And(DateDiff(DateAdd(Now(),-Weekday(Now(),11)),StartDate)>0,DateDiff(DateAdd(Now(),7-Weekday(Now(),11)),StartDate)<=0)).AssignedTo_Text
```

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I get this week's on call person - my list has a start date of a monday and a turnover date of Sunday. I added an or statement to get the next week person.
This week starts previous to day and ends after today.
Next week starts previous to 7 days from now and ends after that date...

```
<Query><Where>
<Or> 
 <And>
    <Leq><FieldRef Name='Start'  /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Leq>
    <Gt><FieldRef Name='Turn_x002d_Over'  /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Gt>
 </And>
 <And>
    <Leq><FieldRef Name='Start'  /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='7'/></Value></Leq>
    <Gt><FieldRef Name='Turn_x002d_Over'  /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='7'/></Value></Gt>
 </And>  
</Or>
 </Where></Query>
```

Comment: How would I display this result via javascript on a SharePoint page? I'm trying to use this result in inline HTML. similar to this: <h5> Current OnCall: [CAML Result]</h5>